# efficient way of transforming a dataframe to map in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a use case where I want to convert the dataframe to a map. For that i am using groupbykey and mapGroups operations. But they are running into memory issues.

Eg:

EmployeeDataFrame

```
EmployeeId, JobLevel, JobCode
1, 4, 50
1, 5, 60
2, 4, 70
2, 5, 80
3, 7, 90
```

```
case class EmployeeModel(EmployeeId: String ,JobLevel: String, JobCode: String)
```

```
val ds : Dataset[EmployeeModel] = EmployeeDataFrame.as[EmployeeModel]
    val groupedData = ds
      .groupByKey(_.EmployeeId)
      .mapGroups((key, rows) => (key, rows.toList))
      .collect()
      .toMap
```

Expected Map

```
1, [(),()]
2, [(), ()]
3, [()]
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: By collecting the map, you're bringing the entire resulting dataset onto the driver node. How big is your resulting dataset? What do you intend to do with it once collected to the driver node?

Comment: There is no way to do it in a "better" way. You will need to have the driver node with more RAM than required for this `Map`.

Comment: Would obtaining a `Map` for each partition work for your use case? That is having several "partial" maps, one on each worker node.

Comment: @Gael Yes, that can work. Can you give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: @memoryz my dataset is quite large but I am trying to create a lookup table and that is the best I could do to create a lookup. I am open to suggestions for creating lookup.

Comment: @itisha Please describe your entire scenario. If you want a lookup table, typically your next step is to do a join, but it's hard to tell without knowing the end to end scenario.